# Different SIP uri scheme in from and to header in Sip Invite

Tags: sip

Scenario:
1. UAC sends INVITE to B2B UA with sip uri in from header and tel uri in To header.
2. To which B2B UA replies with 1xx(Reliable) message with same uri scheme as INVITE i.e. (sip uri in from header and tel in To header).
3. UAC sends PRACK for 1xx with tel uri in both the headers i.e. From and To.
4. After this all 1xx - PRACK and final 200 OK - ACK transaction are with tel uri in From and To header.
5. After final ACK, B2B UA sends Reinvite to UAC with tel uri in both From and To header.

So, my question is Reinvite mentioned in point 5 is correct or should we use same URI scheme used by initial invite mentioned in point 1??

Answer (score 0):

On sending a PRACK, [RFC3262](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3262.txt) states in chapter 4 (UAC behaviour):

> [...] the UAC MUST create a new request with method PRACK.  This request is sent within the dialog associated with the provisional response [...]

[RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-12.2.1.1) states on creating requests within a dialog:

> The URI in the To field of the request MUST be set to the remote URI
> from the dialog state. [...] The From URI of the
> request MUST be set to the local URI from the dialog state.

Therefore the PRACK from step 3 should have contained the same To-URI and From-URI as the INVITE request from step 1.

From that point on both sides use the tel URIs for both From and To header which seems to work fine. That can be explained by the fact that a dialog is identified by the combination call-id/from-tag/to-tag. The From-URI and To-URI don't play a part in this. They could be seen as properties of the dialog.

To answer your question:

In this case it doesn't seem to matter which schemes you use in the ReInvite: both sides just use the To-URI and From-URI as properties of the dialog and update these when they change.

Of course, if this particular UAC ever interfaces with a UAS that is less lenient (requires the To-URI and From-URI to remain constant during the lifetime of a dialog) this behaviour could lead to connection problems.

Comment: I agree that URI scheme is not really the property of dialog, but in my case for the Reinvite UAC sends an error with "4xx Invalid To header, Invalid nameAddress". I'm suspecting that there is some issue on UAC side as UAC itself changed Sip uri to tell after PRACK, but it is not able to match it in reinvite. But need to confirm what should be uri cheme while sending Reinvite

Comment: It appears the UAC doesn't check the To and From headers of received responses, but does check these when receiving an in-dialog request. It wrongfully changes the URI scheme in step 3 but doesn't accept this change itsself. The UAC implementation should be corrected so it doesn't change the scheme in step 3 and then all will work fine. Another approach is that the UAS accepts changes To and From header values (as it now does) for an existing dialog, but doesn't internally change these values. If it then keeps using the original values for in-dialog requests I expect all will work fine.

Comment: If both sides would follow the RFC specification correctly, all message in your scenario (from initial Invite request to ReInvite) would contain one sip URI and one tel URI. Never two tel URIs.